# Why do I get an Object not found error message when I submit an API request

Tags: javascript, urlfetch

working on a project in which I am trying to call an API using JavaScript. It is probably just a stupid mistake I am overlooking, but does anyone know why I keep getting this 'Object not found' message in the console?

[error in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8caG.png)

Here is my code, I have an index.js as well a public script.js.

This is my index.js

```
// import Express library and activate it
import express from "express";
  

const app = express();
// publish our static frontend files
app.use('/',express.static('./public')) 


app.get("/api/ethereum", async (req, res) => {  


        let url = new URL('https://randomuser.me/api/')

    const response = await fetch(url.href)
    const data = await response.json()   


    res.send(data) 
}); 


// Start Express
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => { 
    console.log(`Express is now Live.`) 
    console.log(`Public URL: `+ process.env.PUBLIC_URL)
});
```

Here is my script.js

```
const getData = async () =>{
  console.log('Hello from script.js')
  const response = await fetch('/api/ethereum')
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(data)
}

getData()
```

To make sure it wasn't the actual API not working I tried it with a different API, this [Random User API](https://randomuser.me/) that does not require a key. However the same problem occurs... help?

Comment: where do you get the error? server console? browser console? does the error suggest which line of code is producing it?

Comment: @JaromandaX oops, just updated it with an image of the error. It is in the browser console, and refers to the `console.log(data)` line in the script.js

Comment: so the server is sending `{"message": "Object not found"}` regardless of which URL you use in the server?

Answer (score 0):

You missed "await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/ethereum')" in your script.js

Demo

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get("/api/ethereum", async (req, res) => {
    let url = new URL('https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Lion')
    const response = await fetch(url.href)
    const data = await response.json()
    res.send(data)
});

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Save as `script.js`

```js
const getData = async () => {
    console.log('Hello from script.js')
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/ethereum')
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
}

getData()
```

##### Install Dependency

```
npm install express
```

##### Run Server

```
node server.js
```

##### Run Client

```
node script.js
```

##### Result

[image]